# increment current top value by 3 in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to increment the current top value by 3 in javascript / jquery, but nothing is working.

Here's why:

```
$('#searchInput').css('top', $('#searchInput').css('top')+3);
```

gives me `-22px3`

```
$('#searchInput').css('top', $('#searchInput').css('top')+'3px');
```

gives me `-22px3px`

I want `-19px`, but I can't do `-19px` because then I will add 3 again and again and again.

How can I properly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to parse current top value to integer or float and then add 3 and concat px as string

try like  this:

```
var x = $('#searchInput').css('top');
 $('#searchInput').css('top',parseFloat(x)+3+"px");
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/654/

Comment: Thank you this works, but it is going massively negatively, I need it to go massively possively.

Comment: say you have current top -22 after clicking on increment what next top value you expected?

Comment: if you want next top value to -25 then just replace  `$('#searchInput').css('top',parseFloat(x)+3+"px");` by `$('#searchInput').css('top',parseFloat(x)-3+"px");`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to parse your value using [**parseInt()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) here:

```
$('#searchInput').css('top', parseInt($('#searchInput').css('top'), 10) + 3 + 'px');
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working, but it is going massively negative. I need it to go massively positive.

Answer (score 1):

If your jQuery version is over 1.6, you can use `+=` like this, I believe:

```
$('#searchInput').css('top', '+=3');
```

Otherwise you'll have to do something like this:

```
var t = $('#searchInput').css('top');
$('#searchInput').css('top', t + 3 + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#searchInput').css( "top", "+=3" );
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$('#searchInput').css('top', parseInt($('#searchInput').css('top'), 10) + 3);
```